# Array_combine error: puts out the wrong values and gives only the unique values php

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

hi all i have 2 arrays

```
[0] => CD Alaves
[1] => Granada CF
[2] => Getafe
[3] => CD Leganes
[4] => Barcelona
[5] => Getafe
[6] => Atletico Madrid
[7] => Getafe
[8] => Sevilla
[9] => Athletic Bilbao
[10] => CD Leganes
```

and their corresponding values

```
[0] => 11
[1] => 11
[2] => 11
[3] => 11
[4] => 11
[5] => 10
[6] => 10
[7] => 10
[8] => 10
[9] => 10
[10] => 9
```

I am currently using

```
$teamdata=array_combine($clubs,$stats);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($teamdata);
echo "</pre>";
```

however it outputs as

```
[CD Alaves] => 1
[Granada CF] => 1
[Getafe] => 1
[CD Leganes] => 1
[Barcelona] => -
[Atletico Madrid] => 1
[Sevilla] => 1
[Athletic Bilbao] => -
[Real Betis] => 1
[Espanyol] => 1
[Osasuna] => 1
[Villarreal] => 1
[Real Madrid] => 1
[Levante] => 1
```

giving unique values on the left and 1s on the right

it should read

```
[CD Alves]=>11
[Granada CF]=>11
....
```

Thanks a lot to anyone who sees this and takes the time to respond.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of your problem, including your actual array data (in _code_ form, not like you have currently shown them.)

Comment: The array you are trying to use as the keys has duplicates, you can only have 1 key with a particular value in PHP.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to print the array values like the print_r or are you trying to build a new array with the key => value. Depending on what you are going to do next the solution will be different. Give us some more context and the real code you used, just as CBroe said

Answer (score 0):

As long as your two originating arrays are valid, then `array_combine` works just fine:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
    0 => "CD Alaves",
    1 => "Granada CF",
    2 => "Getafe",
    3 => "CD Leganes",
    4 => "Barcelona",
    5 => "Getafe",
    6 => "Atletico Madrid",
    7 => "Getafe",
    8 => "Sevilla",
    9 => "Athletic Bilbao",
    10 => "CD Leganes"
);

$arr2 = array(
    0 => 11,
    1 => 11,
    2 => 11,
    3 => 11,
    4 => 11,
    5 => 10,
    6 => 10,
    7 => 10,
    8 => 10,
    9 => 10,
    10 => 9
);

$res = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($res);

// Gives:
Array
 (
    [CD Alaves] => 11
    [Granada CF] => 11
    [Getafe] => 10
    [CD Leganes] => 9
    [Barcelona] => 11
    [Atletico Madrid] => 10
    [Sevilla] => 10
    [Athletic Bilbao] => 10
)
```

A working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6da80745eff9ff9b598fe4a2d7fbd8d71d3fb08

Even if your arrays are single values without explicit keys, it will work (php adds numeric indexes anyway)

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
    "CD Alaves",
    "Granada CF",
    "Getafe",
    "CD Leganes",
    "Barcelona",
    "Getafe",
    "Atletico Madrid",
    "Getafe",
    "Sevilla",
    "Athletic Bilbao",
    "CD Leganes"
);

$arr2 = array(
    11,
    11,
    11,
    11,
    11,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    9
);

$res = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($res);

// Prints the same output as above.
```

Comment: Your working example is not working. You input 11 items and only get 8 in return. That is what OP says is the problem, so your code does not do anything.

Comment: Yes, but it's not what OP wants. So is does that make the answer correct and/or useful? No.

Comment: @Andreas if the OP has no idea what are they talking about, it's not the reason to blame the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same problem and this worked for me. Please mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.

Code from @axiac on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671863/19402660

```
// The input arrays
$Array1 = ['bus', 'bus', 'int'];
$Array2 = [2, 18, 10];

// Build the result here
$Array3 = [];

// There is no validation, the code assumes that $Array2 contains
// the same number of items as $Array1 or more
foreach ($Array1 as $index => $key) {
    // If the key $key was not encountered yet then add it to the result
    if (! array_key_exists($key, $Array3)) {
        $Array3[$key] = 0;
    }

    // Add the value associate with $key to the sum in the results array
    $Array3[$key] += $Array2[$index];
}

print_r($Array3);
```

Its output:

```
Array
(
    [bus] => 20
    [int] => 10
)
```

Comment: I gave proper credit, in case you missed. I tried to mark this as a duplicate, but I don't know how - I am new on this platform, as you can see by my user metrics. **Also: this answer gives the exact result OP and others might be after.** Give it a try. As an experienced member, you should be more courteous and prevent shamming on new users, instead constructively educating them.